# maplibre-gl-export : How to get the generated image for creating pdf from other component of the application

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, maplibre-gl

Using maplibre-gl-export plugin for exporting map, I'm looking for a way to get and pass the generated image to other component of my react application? I am able to invoke the click function for generate-button, but not able to get the resultant image. Thank you

Comment: Need more info here - there is pretty clear documentation on how to convert the canvas context to an image in the Mapbox docs.

Comment: I need to print the custom markers as well along with map and other layers. So getting the map canvas alone is not enough in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the map image this is the simplest way:

```
const mapCanvasDataURL = map.getCanvas().toDataURL();
```